# Qt - Verificar se tabela está vazia no banco de dados

Tags: sql, c++, qt

Tenho um aplicação com uma conexão com o banco de dados, ao inicializar a aplicação eu preciso verificar se existe algum registro na tabela, se não deve ser cadastrado um usuário, quando eu executo a query `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM va_admins)` diretamente no banco de dados é retornado 0 se não existir nenhum registro, se existir não é retornado 0, porém na aplicação, sempre é retornado 0, eu estou fazendo a consulta desta maneira:

```
bool Admin::issetAdm()
{

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database();

    if(!db.isOpen()){
        QMessageBox::critical(nullptr, "Falha ao verificar adm", "nenhuma conexão com o banco de dados encontrada");
        qCritical() << "Falha ao verificar: " << db.lastError().text();
        return false;
    }

    QSqlQuery q("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM va_admins)", db);

    if(!q.exec()){
        qCritical() << "Falha ao realizar a consulta: " << q.lastError().text();
        exit(-1);
    }

    //Editado
    while(q.next()){
        qDebug() << q.record().value(q.record().indexOf("id")).toInt();
    }

    q.finish();

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta mudar o *select*, faz um `SELECT COUNT(CAMPO) FROM TABELA (Select Count(id) from va_admins no seu caso)`. Dessa forma você consegue ter um resultado de quantos registros tem.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 1):

Após a execução da consulta com `QSqlQuery.exec(const QString &query)` é necessário posicionar o resultado num registo válido para que os valores possam ser lidos. Pode fazer isto, por exemplo, usando o método next().

Outro pormenor a ter em consideração, é que no resultado da sua consulta não existe uma coluna com nome "id", pelo que o resultado da expressão `q.record().indexOf("id")` é -1.

Fica aqui um pequeno exemplo:

```
QSqlQuery q("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM va_admins)");

while (q.next())
     qDebug() << q.value(0).toString();
```

Fica aqui a tradução de um extrato da seção relevante da documentação, para referência futura.

> **bool QSqlQuery::exec(const QString &query)**
>
> Executa a instrução SQL na variável query. Devolve verdadeiro e define o estado da consulta
>   para activa se a sua execução foi bem sucedida, caso contrário,
>   devolve falso. A instrução da consulta deve usar a sintaxe apropriada
>   para o banco de dados SQL que está sendo consultado (por exemplo, SQL
>   padrão).
>
> Depois que a consulta é executada, a consulta é posicionada em um
>   registro inválido e deve ser navegada para um registro válido antes
>   que os valores de dados possam ser recuperados (por exemplo, usando
>   next ()).

O original, para quem prefere o inglês.

> **bool QSqlQuery::exec(const QString &query)**
>
> Executes the SQL in query. Returns true and sets the query state to
>   active if the query was successful; otherwise returns false. The query
>   string must use syntax appropriate for the SQL database being queried
>   (for example, standard SQL).
>
> After the query is executed, the query is positioned on an invalid
>   record and must be navigated to a valid record before data values can
>   be retrieved (for example, using next()).

Comment: Continua retornando 0

Comment: @SamuelIves, veja a edição. A sua query, não devolve um registo com uma coluna chamada "id". Devolve o resultado do predicado EXISTS. O resultado da expressão "q.record().indexOf("id")" será -1.

Comment: Quem votou negativamente, poderia ajudar-me a alterar a resposta de forma a remover a informação incorreta? Obrigado